# Comparison of Flash 3D Engines

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, 3d, haxe

I am currently digging into the whole Flash 3D stuff and I am quite unsure which engine I should use. I really prefer [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) for development but ActionScript 3 is also fine.
Therefore I would like to ask you about experiences you have made!

If you answer this question please consider the following points:

- Easy to use? Easy to learn?
- Quality / Quantity of documentation?
- Active community?
- Features (lightning/shadows, click detection, collision detection, ...)
- Performance / stability of rendering? (make use of Flash Player 10 features?)
- Quality of rendering?

My current candidates are:

- [Papervision3D](http://www.papervision3d.org/)
- [Alternativa3D](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/)
- [Sandy 3D](http://www.flashsandy.org/) (only engine with native Haxe version)
- [Away3D](http://away3d.com/)

These are the 4 major engines I have found. If you know another one, then please write about it! (I would prefer open source.)

I am looking forward to seeing you opinions.

P.S.: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559014/what-is-the-best-actionscript3-3d-engine) SO question, but it is quite old and does not have satisfying answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well from what I know, Papervision3D is no longer being supported.

In my opinion, Away3D is very good, there is also a "lite" version which is pretty fast as far as I know.
Alternativa3D is very good too, and it's free now it I'm correct.

There are a few other, like Flare3D, Yogurt3D...

In the long run, I'm pretty sure they all have the same major features, so it's up to you to use the one you feel most comfortable with. So you might want to check out the websites and look at the docs and all that.

Also, unless you missed it, adobe are going to be releasing [Molehill](http://jpauclair.net/2010/10/27/molehill/), a hardware accelerated 3D API soon. It has just been announced a Adobe Max, so I think it's safe to say that we might see a change in 3D engines over the next 6/7 months.

Comment: Yep Alternativa3D is now free however it's still a closed source project unfortunately.  They do have perhaps the strongest engine tho with level of detail support and more advanced polygon sorting/culling algorithms than the rest.  Another big plus is they are one of the partners in the Molehill prerelease (another being Frima Studio http://www.zombietycoon.com/MolehillTechDemo.html) so I'd expect their version 8 engine will be available to play with when Molehill hits public beta however i fear it going back to a licensed model.

Comment: Away3D is also one of the partners in the Molehill prerelease.

Comment: wow, miss a day huh? I had no idea that alternativa is free now. Those demos really blew PV3d and Away3d out of the water IMHO. I had no idea PV3D was done for, but can't say I miss it as Away3D has been my goto 3d engine (after five3D). With Molehill in our sight, it looks like 2011 will be a good year for Flash & 3D

Comment: Yeah and you guys might want to check out the latest Away3D demo using Molehill, done with the guys from evoflash: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LAN5GHm5eM